# Jquery element width

Tags: jquery, width, element

I've made a function in order to center-align a submit button in forms :

```
function btnCentrage(element, parent){
    var widthForm = $(parent).innerWidth();
    var widthBtn = $(element).outerWidth();
    var placement = (widthForm - widthBtn) / 2;
    console.log(element + '/' + parent + '/' + widthForm + '/' + widthBtn + '/' + placement);
    $(element).css('margin', '0 '+ placement + 'px');
}
    btnCentrage('#connectForm .btn_small', '.connect_bottom');
```

When I call this function (after DOM loading), it doesn't have any element width or parent width.

Comment: Make sure the parent and the element itself are visible.

Comment: why not just use css? `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: can you post your HTML too please

Comment: I don't really understand why you are centering an element using Javascript though, instead of using plain CSS.

Comment: I've tried both of your solution :
- Yes in DOM elements are loaded and exists $(parent).length =$(element).length = 1
- I've tried width, it won't change anything
It's a floating button expandable so i can't use CSS centering method

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery you just use `width()`.

As explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/width/), you can just do:

```
var widthBtn = $(element).width();
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious reason that would be the case is that it's not finding the element or parent.  Try adding `$(parent).length` and `$(element).length` to your `console.log` debug dump so you see whether it's actually locating your DOM nodes.

Comment: - Yes in DOM elements are loaded and exists $(parent).length =$(element).length = 1

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work so the answer is that the elements are either not being selected correctly (as Ianus says) or your elements are not visible as Shankar says.

And as was also pointed out you can easily use CSS to do this.

Your code: http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/QbvxA/

One possible CSS Version: http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/QbvxA/1/

Comment: It's a floating button expandable so i can't use CSS centering method.

Comment: If you can include some HTML we could probably give you better suggestions.